# import pcap using easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install

I am working in python 2.7.5 and trying to import pcap after installing using the command:

`easy_install pcap`

After installation when I try to import `pcap` in my python shell I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>

    import pcap

ImportError: No module named pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is called redcap

```
import redcap
```

:)

Comment: still I couldn't use pycap modules like packet capture. I want to capture packets using pycap. Let me know what to do or where I am wrong

Comment: Are we talking about pcap (packet sniffer) or pycap (interface to REDCap)?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I meant pcap(packet sniffer). I have a problem in importing it. Please let me know the procedure how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details on what's exactly is not working. Did the library installed correctly? Do you have libpcap installed?
You need to install pypcap to make it work. In my case my setup also missed Pyrex installation. Here is what I need to do to install it:

```
pip install pyrex
pip install pypcap
```

pypcap installation requires you to have gcc compiler to work.

When everything is installed without errors you can import pcap from python:

```
import pcap
```

Regards

Comment: This is what I have done so far:- 1. Install python 2.7.5          2. set environment variables `C:\python27` and`C:/python27/Scripts`.                                             3. `pip install pyrex`. Installation completed with no errors.       4. `pip install pypcap`. Installation not complete ("unable to find `vcvarsall.bat`")       5. `import pcap` in python GUI. no module named pcap